# Datatables can't find CSS/Images in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, datatables, grails-2.1

We are seeing some weirdness on a Grails 2.1.1 app in IE8.

We implemented datatables in a, well, table of data. This datatable works fine locally when running with `grails run-app` in both IE8 (what we have to support) and in Chrome (what we want to use).

If we do `grails war` and `grails run-war` locally we get the same thing -- it looks fine.

But when we deploy it to our Dev environment, which uses tcServer, it looks fine in Chrome but in IE8 it seems that not all the styling is there. There are no headers, for example, and the blank cells have no border. The Datatable *works* fine -- I can search in the input box, and if I click where the header should be, it runs the sort.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between local and remote was IE8 Compatibility Mode. It was turned on locally but the intranet has it shut off. Turning it off locally at least lets us change the CSS rules.